# subscribe to the subject doesn't work. why?

Tags: angular

```
/*import*/
@Component({
selector: 'supfoot-match-single',
templateUrl: './match-single.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./match-single.component.scss']
})
export class MatchSingleComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
private teamSearch = new Subject<any>();
@Input() match: Match;
names = {};
constructor(public teamService: TeamService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getTeamNames();
}

ngOnChanges() {
if (this.match) {
  this.match.teams.forEach((team) => {
    this.teamSearch.next(team.name);
  })

 }
}

getTeamNames() {
 this.teamSearch.subscribe(key => console.log(key));
}

 getTeam(key) {
  return this.names[key];
 }
}
```

I set the value by binding property and 
I call the method getTeamsNames() in order to subscribe to subject teamSearch but it doesn'work .

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: Have you used your debugger to find out if your ngOnChanges is called, what the value of this.match is, if it has teams, etc.? Have you checked your console for errors? Could you post a complete example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr?

Comment: i use the debugger, when ngOnChanges is called, i see the values  of teams in the console

Comment: when i do this.teamSearch.next("Bar") in the ngOnInit(), the subscription work correctly. Why not in the ngOnChanges();

Comment: Strong hint: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZgUMsyoRPHIuVTetIRaL. You could have found that very easily with your debugger. I can only assume that this is the problem, since you didn't provide a plunkr.

Comment: thanks i have fixed the problem. The value of match is binding  at the creation of the component. Now i can use ngOnInit